# Docker swarm routing mesh does not forward UDP traffic after container restart

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, lvs

I have setup a docker stack with a couple services. One of the service is publishing a UDP port that it is listening for traffic on (it happens to be a Wireguard endpoint, but I don't think this is relevant in this case).

So far this is working fine. I can send UDP traffic on the published port of the node and I can see it being forwarded to the virtual interface via the docker bridge (veeth*, docker_gwbridge) and arriving within the container using tcpdump.

When I restart the service container however, the new service container does not get the UDP traffic forwarded correctly anymore. At some point -- and it's currently still unclear to me what exactly the trigger is, but it appears just time -- the traffic suddenly starts flowing through again.

I tcpdump'd all traffic on all interfaces coming towards the mapped port on the host machine and I can see the traffic come in on the hosts interface, leaving the docker_gwbridge and the veeth* interface, but tcpdump'in the mapped port inside the container just stays silent.

I compared the traffic leaving the host before the restart, after the restart and once the container recovers again, and nothing seems to change (i.e. using the same IP addresses and ports).

I found a very [similar, but old post](https://serverfault.com/questions/653636/udp-traffic-from-outside-to-docker-container-is-dropped-after-container-restart) and the Docker issue it links to seems to have been resolved over a year ago. Trying to use the workaround described in the post (flushing the conntrack table by running `conntrack -F` on the host) didn't help either.

I suspect that either conntrack or the docker VIP overlay network are somehow involved in the issue, but my understanding of either of those systems is too limited to even figure out where to start. My searches have not been turning anything up that helped me either.

### Progress Update 1

*tl;dr: traffic is dropped in the LVS network namespace. Everything down to and including LVS seems to be setup correctly though. I can even see the correct LVS marks being applied via iptables, but the traffic doesn't seem make it through LVS routing/masquerading*

I've continued working through this issue over the last couple of days and would like to provide a progress update, since I think it might be valuable to others running into similar problems and might help someone else put the last remaining puzzle pieces into place.

I'm still far from an expert on any of these topics, so please forgive (and correct) me if I misuse any terminology or misrepresent any detail.

A couple of fundamentals:
Docker (Swarm) Networking heavily makes use of Linux Network Namespaces, bridges and virtual IP addresses. Following the flow of any particular stream or series of packets through this setup can be challenging an confusing.
I had no prior experience with Docker Networking, Linux Network Namespaces or virtual IP addresses, how they work or how to interact with them, but I found the following three articles incredibly helpful and would recommend to at least skim over them if you are unfamiliar with these topics, too:

- [Docket Network Namespace Invisible](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-network-namespace-invisible)
- [Docket Network and Network Namespaces in Practive](https://learn-docker.it-sziget.hu/en/latest/pages/advanced/kernel-namespaces-network.html)
- [Swam Networking Deep Dive](https://docker-tutorial.schoolofdevops.com/swarm-networking-deepdive/)

Some key takeaways:

- Linux Network Namespaces are a form of network containerization / isolation. Each network namespace has its entire independent network stack inside the Linux kernel.
- `ip netns` is the canonical way to interact with Linux Network Namespaces and `ip netns exec` can be used to run any command within the context of a particular network namespace.
- Docker uses network namespaces, but does not link them into `/var/run/netns`, which makes them invisible to the canonical Linux tools.
- Docker network namespaces are linked in `/var/run/docker/netns`. You can bind mount the entire folder into `/var/run/netns` or individually link the network namespaces into `/var/run/netns` on a per need basis.
- Each network namespace in `/var/run/docker/netns` belongs to a docker container or network. Which one belongs to which can be a little challenging.
- Containers seem to refer to their network namespace via the `SandboxKey` property. Run `docker inspect <container-id> -f '{{.NetworkSettings.SandboxKey}}'` to obtain it. You could also just use `docker exec` to run arbitrary commands within the container and as such effectively within the container's network namespace.
- For networks it's a little more challenging though. The `docker exec` solution will not work for networks and `docker inspect <network-id>` does not directly refer to any item under `/var/run/docker/netns`. However all the relevant networks were relatively easily identifiable. They two relevant once were linked as `ingress_sbox` and `lb_<first-9-chars-of-swarm-network-id>`.
- Linking both of those network namespaces into `/var/run/netns` allowed me to run commands within them using `ip netns exec`.
- Running tcpdump inside these two network namespaces, the container as well as on the host machine allowed me to see the flow of traffic fully end to end.
- Using `ip netns exec ingress_sbox tcpdump -i any udp` I was also able to see that ingress_sbox was indeed where the traffic was no longer being routed into the container and dropped after a container restart.
- The container gets a new mesh network IP address upon restart and `ip netns exec ingress_sbox conntrack -Ln` I was indeed showing an outdated conntrack entry for the UDP flow.
- Flushing conntrack using `ip netns exec ingress_sbox conntrack -F` did however **not help**. I did not see any new conntrack entries being created.
- I saw traffic coming in on 10.0.0.2 (the container's default gateway and service VIP) and leaving (masqueraded) towards 10.0.0.100 (the IP address of eth0 in the container). It was still unclear to me where that routing/masquerading happened.
- `ip netns exec ingress_sbox iptables -L -t nat` showed that the was a SNAT rule that matched on the `10.0.0.0/24` destination network and on `-m ipvs --ipvs`.
- Turns out IPVS is IP Virtual Server -- the virtual IP address system mentioned above. Running `ip netns exec ingress_sbox ipvsadm -L` shows a round robin (rr) rule masquerading (Masq) traffic to the 10.0.0.100 IP address based on a firewall mark (FWM) of 11962 with an InActConn count of 1 (for my UDP "connection").
- And indeed, if I look at the mangle table using `ip netns exec ingress_sbox iptables -n -t mangle -L` I can see a rule applying the mark (in hex) to all traffic coming in on the mapped UDP port.
- When I restart the container, the mark value changes in iptables as well as the ipvs rule mapping the now changed mark to the container IP address.
- I can even see the packet and byte counter go up for the iptables rule applying the mark using `ip netns exec ingress_sbox iptables -Lnvt mangle`. And while `ip netns exec ipvsadm -L` shows the correct mark rule and masquerade IP address, the InActConn column stays 0 for the entry -- until the container recovers.

### Progress Update 2

I found that `ip netns exec ingress_sbox ipvsadm -Lc` lists LVS's connection table and it indeed includes an entry for the UDP "connection" that remains even after the LVS real server receiving that connection was removed from the pool. There's three points here to be made

1. This might be a bug in LVS. It depends a little on the semantics here and what guarantees LVS is making for real servers that get removed from it's pool (i.e. if LVS guarantees that real servers will continue to receive traffic for active connections even after having been removed from the pool), but there is an argument to be made that if a real server gets removed from the pool it's connections should be cleared or at least flagged as "stale" or "adoptable", *especially* for stateless UDP and "handed" to any other real server in the list, even prior to timeout. If you want LVS to continue serving active connections to it, the real servers weight could be reduce to 0 instead.
2. I've done a lot of googling and I am afraid I am unable to find a way to update, change, remove or flush entries in the LVS connection table. There seem to be some up to [20 year old posts](https://archive.linuxvirtualserver.org/html/lvs-users/2004-06/msg00035.html) on the LVS users mailing that talk about such functionality, but it seems like no-one ever implemented any of it. At least not as far as I can tell. I *really* hope I'm wrong about this, since I would love to just clear out all UDP entries for real-servers having been removed from the pool. I've stated this part as a [separate question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/1156941/remove-drop-tracked-udp-connections-from-lvs-connection-table-ipvsadm-lc).
3. Timeouts. This is one thing that can be changed using `ip netns exec ingress_sbox ipvsadm --set <tcp> <tcpfin> <udp>`. Setting the `<udp>` value affects the UDP connections timeout and a lower value can significantly reduce service interruption (the default is 300 seconds) upon a container update/restart. First I was thinking I could set this value to 0 or some arbitrary low value to flush all UDP connections, but it appears the value only gets updated when the connection is still considered active (i.e. traffic in and out), which isn't the case after the container was stopped. It might be possible to set the value to something lower *before* the container gets stopped though. Would need to make sure this doesn't cause other service interruption though.

Any additional advice or recommendations greatly appreciated.

Comment: Edited the post to clarify that a simple container restart is sufficient to trigger the problem (instead of having to do a full update).

Comment: Edited the post and added a somewhat lengthy progress update based on my own investigation so far.