# Remove/Drop tracked UDP "connections" from LVS connection table (`ipvsadm -Lc`)

Tags: docker-swarm, lvs

Is it possible to explicitly remove or drop a tracked UDP "connection" from the LVS connection table outputted by `ipvsadm -Lc`?

I am using LVS in the context of a Docker Swarm deployment and when I restart a given container exposing a UDP server Docker seems to remove the previous container from the real server pool and add the new container, but any entries in the connection table to the old container remain and have to time out before packets start getting rerouted to the new server. The default timeout is 300 seconds, which effectively leads to a 5 minute service interruption for all clients connected to the stopped container.

One packet scheduling (`--ops`) would probably help in theory, but since the implemented protocol is not *entirely* stateless I would prefer packets from the same socket pair to go to the same real server during normal operation, but rerouted to a different real server as soon as possible once the old one gets removed from the pool.

I don't seem to be able to find any way to instruct LVS to drop or change any specific entry in the connection table. Is this not possible?

Note: this is a follow up question to [Docker swarm routing mesh does not forward UDP traffic after container restart](https://serverfault.com/questions/1156832/docker-swarm-routing-mesh-does-not-forward-udp-traffic-after-container-restart)